# Coefficent Estimates Collinearity Ridge Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python

Suppose you are experiencing collinearity in your data set which is warping estimates of the regression coefficients. If you apply regularisation (in particular ridge regression) to combat this - will the estimates on the coefficients be more reliable or do you still need to mitigate further to combat the collinearity?

Answer (score 0):

Ridge regression reduces the standard errors of the parameter estimates by allowing some bias in those estimates. You can select the amount of bias to allow. There are methods for selecting this so as to get a "best" result - that is, one that minimizes a combination of bias and error.

Comment: Hi - so if collinearity is impacting your coefficients, will regularisation such as ridge reduce this issue?

Comment: Yes, it will. That's its main purpose. However, colinearity doesn't affect your coefficients, it affects their variance.

Comment: So colinearity doesnt impact the expected value of the coefficients just the variance? Are you able to explain how this is the case please?

Comment: It's because the covariance matrix will be nearly singular.

Comment: Thank you. In your experience is regularisation sufficient or is it still required to remove collinear features? Could you calculate the variance of the coefficients and based on this decide if you need to take additional action?